# Asset Compress Plugin not creating cached files with cakephp 2.x

Tags: plugins, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to compress js files using asset compression cakephp plugin.. But it is not creating files to webroot/cache_js folder..
What is wrong ? 
Can you explain ?
Here is my asset_compress.ini code

```
[General]
cacheConfig = true

[js]
paths[] = WEBROOT/js/
cachePath = WEBROOT/cache_js/

[custom.js]
files[] = jquery.js
files[] = jquery-ui.js
```

In my bootstrap.php I loaded

```
CakePlugin::load('AssetCompress', array('bootstrap' => true));
```

Debug level is set to 2.. With debug level 0 also, file is not created

Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

You either need to run the command through the cake console or the following:

To generate and store static assets defined in the asset_compress.ini config or through the AssetCompress helper on the fly. This is to save you having to manually run the console script everytime you change you css or js files.

This is what some will define as a "nasty" hack, I call it a working solution.  It simply runs the console script via the php exec() method every time the AppController beforeFilter() runs and the debug level is greater than 0. So in production where your debug level should be 0, the exec() won't be run.

Add the following to your /app/Controller/AppController.php beforeFilter() function.

```
if(Configure::read('debug') > 0){
  exec(APP.'Console'.DS.'cake -app '.APP.' AssetCompress.asset_compress build -f');
}
```

This is assuming that you can run the normal AssetCompress from the console (linux) or cmd prompt (windows)